# how to restrict textview from accepting some or all special characters?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-injection

I was wondering is there a way I can restrict a user from entering special characters and the user can only input A-z and 0-9 characters and prevent any SQL injections in Android? What is the best practice here?

Thank you.

Comment: You've got 3 answers, please select the one that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `EditText` with these xml options:

```
<EditText 
  android:inputType="text" 
  android:digits="0123456789qwertzuiopasdfghjklyxcvbnm" 
  android:hint="Only letters, digits allowed"/>
```

Though remember if you use `SQLitedatabase`'s query method properly, it does all the SQL Injection preventing by itself.

Answer (score 0):

For the `EditText` you can add [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) Listener

```
edt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        } 

    });
```

In the `onTextChanged()` OR `afterTextChanged()` you can get the text and remove the chars you wouldn't, you can use rejex for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use an `InputFilter` to verify what the user inputs in an `EditText`.

> This method is called when the buffer is going to replace the range
>   dstart … dend of dest with the new text from the range start … end of
>   source. Return the CharSequence that you would like to have placed
>   there instead, including an empty string if appropriate, or null to
>   accept the original replacement.

For example, like this:

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter()
{
    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend)
    {
        if (source.toString().contains("'"))
            return "";
        else
            return null; // Accept original replacement.
    }

};

editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

However, this would be a very poor way of avoiding SQL injections. It would be much better to use [parameterized queries](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Defense_Option_1:_Prepared_Statements_.28Parameterized_Queries.29) in the data layer instead.